# SQL Search and Replace

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Admittedly, I'm a noob when it comes to SQL commands. A hacker inserted a script tag at the end of every post and page on one of my WordPress sites, and I'm trying to do a find and replace in the 'wp_posts' table but I keep getting a #1064 error when I run a Simulate Query. Here's what I have:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=REPLACE(post_content, '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.hcifx.com/troyengelhardt/index1261.php"></script>', '');
```

I get the error no matter what I put inside that first set of 'find' quotes, even if it's something as simple as 'hcifx' instead of the entire script tag shown. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: No  backup to restore from? Fixing holes is likely to leave some so a freshly installed and updated server would be a better idea.

Comment: I've blown up and re-installed WP so many times now, minimized my plugin usage, locked down every directory with htaccess files, deleted unused themes, hardened file permissions, etc. Haven't had a file-level hack in a long time, now getting my database hacked after all that, I have no idea what else I could possibly do that I'm not already doing.

Comment: How do you run this SQL command (what client)? What is the exact error text?

Comment: I'm running the query in PhpMyAdmin. The error says:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.hcifx.com/troyengelhardt/index12' at line 1

Comment: Syntax error messages like that show you the text that occurs at an unexpected place. For example, if you had forgotten the comma after `post_content`, it would be unexpected that another quoted string occurs after it, so that would be the text it shows you in the error. So it's often the case that you should look at your query right *before* the text in the error.

Comment: You should first search for all offending posts before performing a mass update.  `SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%hcifx%'`.  As for the replace issue, I'm not too sure.

Comment: I did search and find all offending posts first, and also backed up my database before making changes. Turned out to be a bug in phpMyAdmin (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the error is a known bug in PhpMyAdmin. The query was valid, but using the 'Simulate Query' function throws an erroneous error. I backed up my database and ran the query as written and it successfully stripped the offending code from all posts in the db table.